# Access to controller from different module in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using angular.layout library (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-layout). And I'd like to toogle panels manualy from directive.

It's controller inside the lib:

```
...
angular.module('ui.layout', [])
  .controller('uiLayoutCtrl', ['$scope', '$attrs', '$element', 'LayoutContainer', function uiLayoutCtrl($scope, $attrs, $element, LayoutContainer)
...
```

This controller has methods `ctrl.toggleAfter` and `ctrl.toggleBefore`.

So, the questions is: how can use it inside my own directive. I tried this way:

```
...
return {
        require: 'uiLayoutCtrl',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            ...
        }

    }
...
```

It doesn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to require the directive instead of the controller:

```
require: 'uiLayout', // both directives in the same element // OR
//require: '^uiLayout' //  your directive is a child of uiLayout
link: function (scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
    // ctrl should be uiLayoutCtrl
}
```